# XSLT to Transform the child Node name according to their occurrence

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

here is my requirement i need to write an XSLT that will transform the node name according to there occurence see my example

XML PRESENT :

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>ABC</OrderNo>
        <ItemDetails>
            <Name>Shirt</Name>
            <Name>Socks</Name>
            <ItemPrice>30</ItemPrice>
            <ItemPrice>40</ItemPrice>
        </ItemDetails>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

XML NEEDED

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>ABC</OrderNo>
        <ItemDetails>
            <Name1>Shirt</Name>
            <Name2>Socks</Name>
            <ItemPrice1>30</ItemPrice>
            <ItemPrice2>40</ItemPrice>
        </ItemDetails>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

Check the Name and item price anem . Like this i have 100 of order in an xml of ORDERS

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using a stylesheet based on the identity transformation to copy most of the XML unchanged and just tweak the little bits that you want to change:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ItemDetails/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}{count(
            preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]) + 1}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to leave the *first* occurrence of each element alone and start numbering from the second one then you could do this in XSLT 2.0 by tweaking the template match pattern:

```
  <xsl:template match="ItemDetails/*[preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}{count(
            preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

But in XSLT 1.0 you can't use `current()` in a `match` pattern so instead you'll have to do the check inside the body of the template, e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ItemDetails/*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}{count(
            preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- this is the first element with this name, so revert to the
             identity behaviour -->
        <xsl:call-template name="ident" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

---

On a more general level this is a rather poor choice of XML format - it's more usual to use the same name for elements that denote the same kind of data, and to express the dependencies between different elements via nesting rather than positioning, e.g.

```
<ItemDetails>
    <Item>
        <Name>Shirt</Name>
        <Price>30</Price>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Socks</Name>
        <Price>40</Price>
    </Item>
</ItemDetails>
```

Comment: Thanks Ian Roberts : Cna we start with the Count 0 like that . Im trying but im not getting like this <Name>Shirt</Name> <Name1>Socks</Name>

Comment: @saikri as I asked in a comment to the question - do you need XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  The two tags are supposed to be mutually exclusive.